# semaphore shmget() what does semflg = 384 do?

Tags: c, semaphore

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

key_t  key    = IPC_PRIVATE;
int    id;
int    semflg = 384;

id = shmget( key, 8192, semflg );
```

Can someone tell me what affect the value of 384 has in semflg?

Answer (score 1):

The manpage of **shmget** says:

> In addition to the above flags, the least significant 9 bits of
>          shmflg specify the permissions granted to the owner, group, and
>          others. These bits have the same format, and the same meaning, as
>          the mode argument of open(2).

So let's check the manpage of **open**:

```
The following symbolic constants are provided for mode:
- S_IRWXU  00700 user (file owner) has read, write, and execute permission
- S_IRUSR  00400 user has read permission
- S_IWUSR  00200 user has write permission
- S_IXUSR  00100 user has execute permission
- S_IRWXG  00070 group has read, write, and execute permission
- S_IRGRP  00040 group has read permission
- S_IWGRP  00020 group has write permission
- S_IXGRP  00010 group has execute permission
- S_IRWXO  00007 others have read, write, and execute permission
- S_IROTH  00004 others have read permission
- S_IWOTH  00002 others have write permission
- S_IXOTH  00001 others have execute permission
```

The integer value **384** is encoded as **110000000** in binary, which corresponds to the flags **600**, that is `S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR`:

- user has write permission
- user has read permission

---

Whoever wrote that piece of code spared 2 minutes of his life and wasted much more time of the lives of many others, me included.

Congratulations. :)

---

**edit:** thanks to @Fabio Turati for pointing out a major error ;)

Comment: Are you sure 101111110 corresponds to the flags 374? I'd say it's 576. That is: user has read and execute, group has read, write, and execute, and others have read and write. And even before that: are you sure 384 is encoded like that in binary? Shouldn't it be 110000000? That is, user has read and write, and everyone else has nothing? Your number, 101111110, is actually the binary encoding of 382, not 384. Can you please check?

Comment: @FabioTurati I mistyped the initial number in python, and from there it all went downhill. Thanks for pointing out the mistake :)